# InvalidOperation: (sh.exe:String) [Set-ProcessMitigation], InvalidOperationException

Tags: git, powershell, aslr

I had a problem with installing `npm install ng-factory`. I asked in `NPM` community and they said this is a git problem with `ASLR`. So I found this command to add my git `.exe` files to windows `ASLR` disabled files:

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\*.exe" | %{ Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disa >> ble ForceRelocateImages }
```

But the result is:

```
Set-ProcessMitigation : Multiple matches found.
At line:1 char:58
+ ... *.exe" | %{ Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disa >> ble ForceRel ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (sh.exe:String) [Set-ProcessMitigation], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Multiple mitigation policies found that may match the given process name. Please specify
    the full path to be matched instead.,Microsoft.Samples.PowerShell.Commands.SetProcessMitigationsCommand
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT:
I tried this command:

```
Get-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\*.exe" | %{ Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disable ForceRelocateImages }
```

But still gives me this error message:

```
Set-ProcessMitigation : Multiple matches found.
At line:1 char:58
+ ... *.exe" | %{ Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disable ForceRelocat ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (sh.exe:String) [Set-ProcessMitigation], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Multiple mitigation policies found that may match the given process name. Please specify
    the full path to be matched instead.,Microsoft.Samples.PowerShell.Commands.SetProcessMitigationsCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you got the script from but

```cs
#                THIS SHOULDN'T BE HERE  ||||
Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.Name -Disa >> ble ForceRelocateImages
```

It should be:

```cs
Set-ProcessMitigation -Name $_.FullName -Disable ForceRelocateImages
```

Edit: changed `Name` to `FullName` as per the comments

Comment: So now it's different question (even though error is the same) and I don't have answer yet :)

Comment: @user145959 you can try use `$_.FullName` instead `$_.Name`

Comment: Glad to hear that. Added to the answer